# _id like variable logstash output email

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I would use _id (metadata) like variable in my output mail.
but it wouldn't work because it can't considerate _id like variable.
someone have idea ?
I make my output on this way :

````
elasticsearch {
     hosts => [ "https://xxx:9200" ]
     ssl => true
     ssl_certificate_verification => false
     user => "admin"
     password => "admin"
     index => "apache"
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
if [tags] {
email {
to => "xxx"
address => "smtp.gmail.com"
port => 587
username => "xxx"
password => "xxx"
use_tls => true
body => "something happened: %{message} http://xxx/5601/app/discover#/doc/82de0080-acd9-11eb-a4b8-614232a13000/indexname?id=%{id}"
}}} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed differently and leverage the [Alerting & Actions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/alerting-getting-started.html) feature in Kibana.

You can set an alert on a [custom query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/alert-type-es-query.html) (e.g. `tags` exist) and decide to send the alert [via email](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/email-action-type.html).

**UPDATE:**

When using OpenDistro, you have access to their [Alerting plugin](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/) that works in a similar way and that you can use to send your alerts.

Comment: yes I tried before but I use open distro and it's not greatfull  with OD.

Comment: Of course, that feature is not in OpenDistro, but OD provides another [Alerting plugin](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/) that works in a similar way and that you can use to send your alerts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to create an email containing a direct link to the document in question.

You can achieve this with three small changes to your existing configuration.

1. Generate an 'id' string during the `filter` stage of the pipeline
2. Use that string as `document_id` in the elasticsearch output
3. Use that string in your email output template

By default, Elasticsearch will generate a random `_id` which is not shared with Logstash. That's why we need to do all three of these steps.

#### Generate an ID string

The [UUID](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-uuid.html) and [Fingerprint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-fingerprint.html) filter plugins can help here. I'll use UUID because it's simpler:

```rb
filter {
  uuid {
    target => "[@metadata][uuid]"
  }
}
```

This generates a random UUID, which should be adequate for your purposes. If you'd prefer to use a consistent hash (e.g. for deduplication), then use Fingerprint.

#### Set `document_id` to the ID string

Use the UUID as `_id` by adding `document_id => "[@metadata][uuid]"` to your elasticsearch output.

```rb
elasticsearch {
     hosts => [ "https://xxx:9200" ]
     ssl => true
     ssl_certificate_verification => false
     user => "******"
     password => "******"
     index => "apache"
     document_id => "[@metadata][uuid]"
}
```

More detail in the Elasticsearch output plugin docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id)

#### Include the ID string in email output `body` template

Your `body` line should be updated to include `%{[@metadata][uuid]}`.

```rb
   body => "something happened: %{message} http://xxx/5601/app/discover#/doc/82de0080-acd9-11eb-a4b8-614232a13000/indexname?id=%{[@metadata][uuid]}"
```

#### Note regarding Kibana index pattern reference

I assume `82de0080-acd9-11eb-a4b8-614232a13000` is the object ID of the *Kibana index pattern* relevant to the ES indices here. For other index-patterns, or for others attempting the same thing, the simplest way to determine the appropriate string is the navigate in Kibana to a single document then replace with the ID variable above.

Alternatively, at the time of writing (May 2021) you can replace that string with the word `mixed`, like so:

```
http://xxx/5601/app/discover#/doc/mixed/indexname?id=%{[@metadata][uuid]}
```

This may break in future, and you'll still need to get `indexname` right.